# Checking TS errors on pre-commit hook in a Vue app

Tags: typescript, vue.js, lint, pre-commit, husky

So in our app we have a git hook using husky for pre-commit.
When someone committing code, it runs pre-commit code -

```
#!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"

nvm use
npx lint-staged
```

and in the package.json is -

```
"lint-staged": {
  "*.(js|ts|vue)": "eslint --cache --fix --max-warnings=0"
}
```

It detects well lint errors, but it doesn't detect problems in the typescript of the project, let's say when I call a non callable variable -
[image: Calling a non callable variable]

This thing pass the lint check.

I get it that I'm running only lint, but is there an easy way to check typescript as well? The only option that I can check it right now is running a build which takes way too long to be in a commit hook.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a script in your `package.json` that only do the type-checking, then call that script in your pre-commit hook

```
"type-check": "vue-tsc --noEmit",
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was missing